# Python. Override a method without creating a derived class and call the original method

Tags: python

I have a function like:

```
ModuleA.py

Class FooClass:
    def fooMethod(self):
        self.doSomething()
```

Now i want to override that method, but without deriving from that class and call the overridden method from inside:

```
ModuleB.py

from ModuleA import FooClass

def _newFooMethod(self):
    if(not hasAttr(self,"varA "):
        self.varA = 0
    #Do some checks with varA

    #CALL ORIGINAL fooMethod

FooClass.fooMethod = _newFooMethod
```

Things to know:

- I don't have access to the FooClass.
- I don't have access to the instances of FooClass since they are many and not in a single place.
- As you can see, what i really want is to decorate the fooMethod.
- I also want to create a variable like "varA" to use it in the _newFooMethod. I do that by first checking if it is already created and creating it if not, but i don't know if it is the best way to do it...

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access to the FooClass?

Comment: I mean it is a third-party class not accessible by me since it is installed in a device's firmware

Comment: If you do not have acces to either tha class or any instance then you can't change anything. I don't not get why you even care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use inheritance. What you do is called monky patching!

So you can do the following:

```
ModuleB.py

from ModuleA import FooClass

# Preserve the original function:
FooClass.originalFooMethode = FooClass.fooMethode

def _newFooMethod(self):
    if(not hasAttr(self,"varA "):
        self.varA = 0
    #Do some checks with varA

    #CALL ORIGINAL fooMethod
    self.originalFooMethode()

FooClass.fooMethod = _newFooMethod
```

Comment: Should "FooClass" be imported from ModuleB when used, to ensure the method is actually replaced by the custom version ?

Comment: @Antwane good point. As long as you want only the Instaces in ModuleB to be affected from this patch the above code is ok otherwise you have to use `import ModuleA` and use `ModuleA.FooClass` and ensure that Module B is the fist Module in your Project which loads ModuleB.